# Swift: Control dependent functions, avoid callback hell

Tags: swift

How can I design the following code better? I have the feeling that the code can lead to a callback hell. Every function depends on completion of the previous one.

**Current Solution (bad):**

```swift
@objc func restoreDocuments(UID: UID) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        //1. Load user details from RemoteServer#1
        UserManager.RemoteServer.loadUserFromRemoteServer(userUID: UID) { (userDict) in

            //2. After user is loaded save user to local database
            UserManager.LocalDB.saveUser(userData: userDict, completion: {

                    //After User is restored, restore his documents from RemoteServer#2 (IDs provided in userDetails)
                    let userDocumentsArray = getDocumentIDsFromUser(userUID: UID)

                    //Loop through array to get every ID 
                    for ID in userDocumentsArray{

                        //load each document by ID
                        loadDocumentsRemote(documentID: ID) { (document) in

                                //Save loaded document 
                                saveDocumentsLocal(document, completion: {

                                        //At the end populate the UI with the restored documents
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            populateUI()
                                        }
                                })
                        })
                    }
            })
        }
    }
```

I would imagine something like the following code. But I don't know how to communicate the different steps among each other. So that task 2 does not start before task 1 is finished.

**What I imagine (simplified):**

```swift
 @objc func restoreDocuments(UID: UID) {

    //1. Restore User
    UserManager.RemoteServer.loadUser(UID){ (user) in }
       UserManager.LocalDB.saveUser(user)
    // -> WHEN FINISH PROCCED TO STEP 2 

    //2. Load Documents
    UserManager.LocalDB.getDocumentIDsFromUser( { (IdArray) in

        for ID in IdArray {
            RemoteServer.DocManager.loadDocument(ID) { (retrievedDocument) in 
               LocalDB.DocManager.saveDocument(retrievedDocument)
            }
        }
    }
    // -> WHEN FINISH PROCCED TO STEP 3 

    //3. Finish
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       populateUI()
    }

}
```

But how do I do that? And is that a good approach at all ?

Comment: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by extracting the closures into variables:

```
let onDocumentsSaved: () -> Void = {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       populateUI()
    }
}

let onDocumentsLoaded: (Document) -> Void { document in
   saveDocumentsLocal(document, completion: onDocumentsSaved)
}

// continue with other closures, in reverse order of execution
```

That will clear up your indentation and the steps will be clearly visible. If you want to wait for multiple steps (e.g. multiple documents) in one step, you can use `DispatchGroup`.

Every step can be also easily extracted into a function, or, you can make your class to work as a state machine.

Also, it's a good idea to group connected methods into utility methods, e.g. your *load* and *save* can be grouped to one method with a completion handler, for example:

```
func loadUserAndSave(userId, completion)
func loadDocumentsAndSave(userId, completion)
```

then your method could be simplified to (pseudocode):

```
loadUserAndSave(userId) {
    loadDocumentsAndSave {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           populateUI()
        }
    }
}
```

Which again would be much simpler .

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at futures and promises, two related design patterns that address this issue very well. My company uses BrightFutures, a third party library that offers a decent implementation of both.